# Foreign key part of a multi-Primary key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My tables are the following :

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    param1            varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
    id_table1         BIGINT NOT NULL,
    pk2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    param2 varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_table1 FOREIGN KEY (id_table1) REFERENCES merging_configuration(id)
);

ALTER TABLE merging_configuration_type
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_table1, pk2);
```

I really need the `(id_table1, pk2)` to be the key

So In hibernate I wrote the following classes:

```
@Entity(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String param1;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_table1")
  private List<Table2> table2list;

  // constructors, getters, setters…
}
```

```
@Entity(name = "table2")
public class Table2 {

  @EmbeddedId
  private Table2Id id;

  private String param2;

}
```

```
@Embeddable
public class Table2Id implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "id_table1")
  private Long idTable1;

  @Column(name = "pk2")
  private String pk2;

}
```

So everything compile and the get functions works perfectly but I cannot POST or PUT anything with the Table1Repository.save(entity):

- case 1: the keys in `table2List` of my `entity` **are the same** as  for the database: the `param1` updates but not `param2`
- case 2: `table2List` of my `entity` **does not contains existing data** in the database: I have this error in the logs:

```
[ERROR] o.h.e.j.s.SqlExceptionHelper - ERROR: a NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint of the column "id_table1" in the relation "table2".
  Meaning: The failed row contains (null, myPK2, myParam2)
```

- case 3 : `table2List`of my `entity` **contains non existing data** in the database: the .save throw an error with the following message : `Unable to find path.Table2 with id Table2Id(idTableB=1, pk2=myPK2)`

Could anyone help me ? I think there is a problem with my entities but I don't see anything else that could work

Thanks a lot

Comment: `I really need the (id_table1, pk2) to be the key` - No you don't. You already have a primary key in table2.

Comment: Thank you @K.Nicholas for answering my question but I do need the tuple (id_table1, pk2) to be unique not pk2 (I should have named the tuple (pfk1, pk2))

I could also have another pk in table2 to avoid the tuple but that means that the tuple (id_table1, pk2) will not be unique. That bothers me but if I have no other choice I will do that and make sure the database is filled respecting this constraint

Answer (score 0):

How about mapping it like this instead?

```java
@Entity(name = "table1")
public class Table1 {

  @Id
  private Long id;

  private String param1;

  @ElementCollection
  @CollectionTable(name = "table2")
  @JoinColumn(name = "id_table1")
  @MapKeyColumn(name = "pk2")
  private Map<String, Table2> table2Elements;

  // constructors, getters, setters…
}
@Embeddable
public class Table2 {

  private String param2;

}
```

This way, you can use the database schema that you seem to want and a model that fits the schema better.